# Now there's something you don't see every day

Tags: discussion

In the last couple days 20 questions have been posted. Number of answers? One. Total. Don't think I've ever seen it so quiet here before.

Everyone all right? Hope it's not Covid. Or people getting locked up for storming the Capitol. :P (Okay, that's a bit too dark...my apologies.)

Hope y'all are safe and a prosperous 2021 awaits you. (Can't be any worse than 2020 was...right?)

B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm not convinced this should be posted as an answer, but I still have a long way to go to understand Meta :)*

Thank you for checking in, B Layer. I think we all could use a little of that, now and then.

Let me go ahead and say that, personally, another semester is starting and grad-school is, well, busy. OTOH, I've answered a number of questions this morning.

#### Most importantly

I hope the rest of the community is OK. I wish I had resources to link to for those that may not be. (To that end, if you have some to share, edit this post or start a Community Wiki answer?)

And remember, it could always be worse. You could be stuck in Notepad.

Comment: Green check mark for you based on the not at all arbitrary criteria "who replied first". ;)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for asking @BLayer!

Indeed I have been mostly away for the last 10 days or so, last week was super busy at work and this week I took a few days off to work on the house... We're expecting a baby in a couple of months (my third kid, another boy) so even though we already have a lot, there are still preparations for the arrival.

Everybody is healthy and thankfully nobody got COVID! We are super isolated from friends (especially with the pregnancy) and our families live abroad. We do get to go out and enjoy the parks and nature, which is a little harder these wet and cold months but I think we're already aclimated to it at this point.

I hope you and yours are doing well! Happy 2021, let's hope after a blip on the first week, this year things are going to start getting better and we'll end the year at least closer to what normal is.